# How to configure log4j2 JDBCAppender with DB2 in WebSphere Liberty Profile

Tags: db2, websphere, log4j2, websphere-liberty

I am trying to use the log4j2 JDBCAppender in my Java EE application in WebSphere Liberty Profile with a DataSource. I'm wondering, if I have a configuration error, because I am seeing the following error in my log:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: DSRA9350E: Operation Connection.commit is not allowed during a global transaction.  
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.commit(WSJdbcConnection.java:778)  
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.commitAndClose(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:139)  
    ... 84 more  
2014-11-20 20:23:33,663 ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender OneViewPrimaryLogDatabase org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Failed to commit transaction logging event or flushing buffer.
```

Here is my log4j config data:

```
    <JDBC name="OneViewPrimaryLogDatabase" tableName="IONEVIEW.LOG">  
        <DataSource jndiName="jdbc/OneViewPrimaryLogDataSource" />  
        <Column name="LOGDATE" isEventTimestamp="true" />  
        <Column name="LOGGER" pattern="%logger" isUnicode="false" />  
        <Column name="LOGLEVEL" pattern="%level" isUnicode="false" />  
        <Column name="MESSAGE" pattern="%message" isUnicode="false" />  
    </JDBC>
```

And here is my DataSource config from WLP:

```
<jdbcDriver id="Db2V105JdbcDriver">
    <library id="Db2V105JdbcDriverJars">
        <fileset dir="C:/IBM/DB2V105/java" includes="db2jcc4.jar db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar"/>
    </library>
</jdbcDriver>
<dataSource id="OneViewPrimaryLogDataSource" jdbcDriverRef="Db2V105JdbcDriver" jndiName="jdbc/OneViewPrimaryLogDataSource" type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource">
    <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="OVHALOGP" password="XXXX" portNumber="60008" user="myuser" serverName="myserver"/>
</dataSource>
```

Does anyone see anything I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone resolved this issue by checking "Non-transactional data source" in WAS:

http://websphereissues.wordpress.com/2013/08/30/dsra9350e-operation-connection-commit-is-not-allowed-during-a-global-transaction/

Can you give that a try?

Answer (score 2):

[Remko's hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27074127/3701228) might be correct, for Liberty to achieve that add `transactional="false"` to datasource definition in `server.xml`:

```
<dataSource transactional="false"  ...>
```